# Updating a Container to display new JApplet

Tags: java, applet, awt, layout-manager, repaint

I know this can be done because I've managed to do it around a year ago, but since then I haven't had to do so. Anyways, what I want to do is when a button is clicked it creates a new applet over the pre-existing applet; sort of like an old flash videogame. I'm almost sure it makes use of a method such as revalidate() or repaint() but I still can't seem to get it working. Also, I have container set as a global variable so I can edit it in an actionPerformed method.

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      if(e.getSource() == about)
      {
         c.removeAll();
         About a = new About();
         c.add(a);
         c.revalidate();
      }
      else if(e.getSource() == start_game)
         System.out.println("Start - Coming Soon");
      else if(e.getSource() == highscores)
         System.out.println("HighScores - Coming Soon");
   }
```

I know the problem is within the actionPerformed method, but just don't know what error I'm making. What I'm attempting to do is to remove everything from the current container, add About (which is also a JApplet), and revalidate/repaint it (both methods won't work).

If anyone has any expertise within JApplets or knows this problem I would appreciate any responses.

Comment: Use a `CardLayout` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, thankfully. I was on the right track but I was trying to add a JApplet to the container instead of the contentpane. I used this

```
     About a = new About();
     getContentPane().removeAll();
     a.init();
     getContentPane().add(a);
     getContentPane().revalidate();
```